# correct format of SaleArgs parameter for nft_approve msg

Tags: nearprotocol

I am having trouble setting a correct message/sale_condition with the contract from the nft-tutorial. My code is as follows;

```
    const price = parseNearAmount('1');
    let sale_conditions = {
      near: price
    };

    let args = {
      token_id: tokenId,
      account_id: marketId,
      msg: JSON.stringify({ sale_conditions })
    }

    let GAS = "200000000000000";
    let deposit = parseNearAmount('0.6');
    
    await contract.nft_approve(args, GAS, deposit);
```

But I keep getting the following error

`{"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: panicked at 'Not valid SaleArgs: Error(\"invalid type: map, expected a string\", line: 1, column: 19)', src/nft_callbacks.rs:78:50"}}`

I have checked the arguments and as far as I can tell they are a string format. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which tutorial are you referring to? Is it possible to get a link to the github repo?

Comment: Will it work if you remove the `msg` from args? I just wonder if a cross contract call happens, and `msg` isn't formatted properly (even though it's a string when you send it)?

Comment: This is the tutorial / repo https://github.com/near-examples/nft-tutorial/tree/8.marketplace

Removing msg actually worked, so I may have to set the price in a separate call. I will give it a go now, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have created an answer, and I think maybe we need to change the format of `msg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are following this tutorial https://docs.near.org/docs/tutorials/contracts/nfts/approvals#marketplace-integrations

I think maybe you need to edit the `sale_condition` to the appropriate format

```ts
const price = parseNearAmount('1');
let sale_conditions = price; // updated this line to match expected format for cross contract call

let args = {
  token_id: tokenId,
  account_id: marketId,
  msg: JSON.stringify({ sale_conditions })
}

let GAS = "200000000000000";
let deposit = parseNearAmount('0.6');

await contract.nft_approve(args, GAS, deposit);
```

args will then look something like this:

```
{token_id: 'someTokenId', account_id: 'someAccountId', msg: '{"sale_conditions":1YoctoNear}'}
```

The tutorial expects this format for `msg`, as it's passed to a cross-contract call to [this contract](https://github.com/near-examples/nft-tutorial/blob/8.marketplace/market-contract/src/nft_callbacks.rs#L75,), and `sale_conditions` is expected to be of the type: `SalePriceInYoctoNear`, which is defined to be a `U128` ([link to repo](https://github.com/near-examples/nft-tutorial/blob/8.marketplace/market-contract/src/lib.rs#L36))

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you, I owe you a beer!